# Share variable with all views

Tags: php, laravel-5, global-variables, laravel-5.5

I'm trying to make global variable by using this

```
View::share('key', 'value');
```

As the documentation  I put it in the AppServiceProvider

```
 public function boot()
    {
        $reviews = Comment::where('view','0')->count();

        // Sharing is caring
        View::share('reviews_number', $reviews);
    }
```

but when I try to use  reviews_number  as a variable  I get undefined  variable

> Undefined variable: reviews_number

Comment: How do you access your `reviews_number` in your view?

Comment: I access it directly  in blade file  {{reviews_number}}   it works on all views except the one that has constructor in the controller

Comment: try {{$reviews_number}}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to try this in the same `boot` method:

```
\View::composer('*', function ($view) {

   $reviews = Comment::where('view','0')->count();

   $view->with('reviews_number', $reviews);
});
```